# distributed tensorflow using docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I am experimenting with distributed tensorflow and an [example](https://ischlag.github.io/2016/06/12/async-distributed-tensorflow/) project.
Running the project on the same docker container seems to work well. As soon as you run the application on different conatiners, they cannot connect to eachother.

I don't really know the problem, but I think this is because docker and tensorflow open ports which have to be concatenated to connect to the application like localhost:[docker-port]:[tf-port]

Do you think my guess is correct? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Distributed Tensorflow opens up ports at [hostname]:[portnumber].  Host names can either be a DNS name, localhost, or an ip address.  Running two on a local host (you can open two terminals, or launch two of them in separate threads, to test if it works in the same docker).

-- Having not dealt with docker much, you should probably look for answers about how to get ip/ports to communicate between docker instances (on the same computer).  I think that should be enough.  

-- Perhaps there is some port forwarding that you will have to do.

Comment: can you add the docker run you use when running the containers? my guess is that you simply did not forward the gRPC ports (-p) so the containers cannot communicate